# How many way points can I pass in the URL? Can I pass more than 100 way points?

Tags: here-api, here-routing

I've been using HERE api to calculate the roughness profiles of the route. I need to pass more than 100 waypoints to get the IRI index. Is it possible to pass n number of waypoints or is there certain limit to it?

Answer (score 0):

We only support GET method, POST will allow more, but it is not (yet) supported currently support whatever URL length limits allow.. So something like 100+ waypoints, but for optimising the route, there is a separate service which solves this is provided below.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-waypoints/dev_guide/topics/quick-start-simple-car.html